# Apply method to all keys in javascript object which match condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, loops

I would like to apply a function to all methods in a JSON object which have the a name matching a condition in my case "filename". The problem is that that filename is a nested property in the JSON object it is usually just nested 1 level but could potentially be more. I have considered just async.each though the object and just see if that object has the property i want and run my function but that does not seem efficient.

An example object is

```
"hello"{
      "name": "Distribution Board 5",
      "Filename": "helloworld.png",
      "id": "5",
      "location": "somewhere",
      "description": "something",
}
"test"{
      "testproperty": 123
      "anothertest": 456
}
"extra": [
        {
          "Filename": "image.png",
          "Tag": "It's just a square",
          "Deleted": false
        }
]
```

Would you be able to suggest an efficient implementation to the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const object = {
  hello: {
    name: 'Distribution Board 5',
    Filename: 'helloworld.png',
    id: '5',
    location: 'somewhere',
    description: 'something'
  },
  test: {
    testproperty: 123,
    anothertest: 456,
    nestedproperty: {
      mismatching: 'key',
      Filename: 'test.jpg'
    }
  },
  extra: [{
    Filename: 'image.png',
    Tag: 'It\'s just a square',
    Deleted: false
  }]
}

function walk(o, fn, key) {
  switch (typeof o) {
    case 'object':
      if (o) {
        Object.entries(o).forEach(
          ([key, value]) => walk(value, fn, key)
        )
        break
      }
    default:
      fn(key, o)
      break
  }
}

walk(object, (key, value) => {
  if (key === 'Filename') console.log(`Found ${value}`)
})
```

Here's a `walk()` function that works on JSON-serializable objects. The callback function `fn` can perform the logic you need.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think `async.each` is needed here. It could be done with a little code like this:

```
const run = (obj) => Object.keys(obj).find(
    x => x === "Filename" 
        || typeof obj[x] === "object" 
        && obj[x]
        && run(obj[x])
);

run(YourObjectHere)
```

It'll simply go recursively though all your keys and check if one of them is "Filename".

Probably this could be improved with usage of `Object.keys(x).includes` but it would get more complex do all depends on how many objects your set contains.

Comment: Thanks for the response but when I run this with my set I get a " RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded". The set that i'm running on it is a total of about 206 lines when prettified json. Also that soulution from what I understand just finds if there is a property called filename, is there a way for if it finds filename to then apply a method to it

Comment: This will recurse infinitely for any string value whose key does not match `Filename`, that's why this is failing.

Comment: Is there anyway to get it to not crash the node app. But in the set i gave it there was definitely a few properties which were called "Filename"

Comment: Funny... I must have made a typo... Sorry, for not running this prior to posting - will edit soon. Edit: yep, circular reference is an issue.

Comment: Indeed anything not string did fail - I fixed the code to recurse only if there's an object - if the source of your objects is a JSON it won't crash anymore and it's a little simpler than the other case.

Comment: `run({ foo: null, Filename: 'bar.png' })`